# Android SQLite syntax error in foreign key on cascade

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, syntax-error, cascade

I'm creating tables in my android app. I want this photo table's records to be deleted when the delivery order record is deleted.

This SQL runs, but doesn't include the constraint:

Photo Table:

```
CREATE TABLE photos ( 
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
orderid INTEGER , 
uri TEXT , 
datetime TEXT , 
lattitude REAL , 
longitude REAL , 
FOREIGN KEY ( orderid )  
REFERENCES deliveryorder ( _id ) )
```

but when I add the constraint, I get a syntax error "near CASCADE"

Photo Table:

```
CREATE TABLE photos ( 
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
orderid INTEGER ,
uri TEXT ,
datetime TEXT , 
lattitude REAL ,
longitude REAL ,
FOREIGN KEY ( orderid )  REFERENCES deliveryorder ( _id )  ON DELETE CASCASDE  )
```

Here's the error message:

```
    06-10 11:09:55.944: E/AndroidRuntime(26269): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.pbs.deliverytrack1/com.pbs.deliverytrack1.MainActivity}:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CASCASDE":
syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
CREATE TABLE photos ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, orderid INTEGER , uri TEXT , datetime TEXT , lattitude REAL , longitude REAL , FOREIGN KEY ( orderid )  REFERENCES deliveryorder ( _id )  ON DELETE CASCASDE  )
```

I've searched through a bunch of answers that appear to be related, but I can't find one that addresses this specific problem. I know it's probably something easy, but I don't have a lot of experience with SQL.

- I am turning on foreign keys with the pragma. I use the pragma both
  in onCreate and in onOpen.
- The database version is the one that comes with Gingerbread, so
  this should all be supported.

Obviously, I'm doing something stupid, but can't figure it out.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: I believe that sqlite3 (the underlying engine) supports the syntax but has no implementation for referential integrity, and that in order to make it work you must also add triggers to your database and perform the cascading within them.

Comment: According to the documentation I've found, foreign keys are supported. I can use Triggers, but would prefer the neater solution, if possible. The docs are here: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you misspelled `CASCASDE`. try `CASCADE`. it should work better.

Comment: oh geez, that was embarrassing. Thanks!